# Is it okay to use SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

Tags: mysql, database

Is it okay to use

```
  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

to import or delete contents from database that have foreign keys on many tables?

Comment: [tag:mysql]? If so, please add that tag. If not, please add a suitable tag for your database system.

Comment: Why do you want to disable referential checks?

Comment: Because every time i try to import my database it throws a foreign key check error.

Comment: @Tarun: after doing some more searching, I am no longer sure the answer is that simple. I have removed it for now and will try to find a more detailed source.

Comment: If you use it,your database will become inconsistent.

Comment: Found one for now.
Used SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; at the beginning and then re enabled checking at the end of file using
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;